# Specifying how many numbers after a decimal point

Tags: ruby, floating-point, precision, floating-point-precision

```
 a = '60.950'
 b = a.to_f

 puts a # => 60.950
 puts b # => 60.95
```

I want to display three digits after the decimal point everytime. How can I force `0` at the end of `b`?

Comment: As the answers so far show, use the format string '%.3f'. Beyond that, it's idiomatic in Ruby to use [String's `%` ("format") method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-25): `'%.3f' % 60.95 # => "60.950"`

Comment: [String's % ("format") method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-25): Just to update the link from @theTinMan

Answer (score 12):

Use [sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

```
sprintf('%.3f', 60.95)
# => "60.950"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the mother of the formatting methods, such as `String#%` or `printf` or `sprintf`, which is `Kernel#format`

```
puts format('%.3f', 0)
```

The others refer to this, and the `Kernel#format` documentation has the full documentation tables.